# Possible to change location of the login landing?

Tags: wordpress

Post WP login, either in WP or WPMU, can I change the url of where the user lands. Example: Once user has logged into WP, I want them to be directed to the landing index.php of the main website (home page) instead of the User Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

This WP plugin seems to do exactly what you need. Not sure about WPMU but maybe you can leverage the functionality:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirect-my-login/

Good luck!